# How can I make the entered text and checkbox text go to the same textfield?

Tags: javascript, jquery

when the project name is entered, it populates in the same text field as the checked boxes text but at the top of the field.

I also want to create a button for sending the completed form if that's possible

html

```
    <div class="name">
            <form>
                <label for="projectname">Project name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="pname" name="pname"><br>
                <br>
        </div>
                <br>
      <div class="series1"> 
        <tr><input type="checkbox" rel="textbox1" name="Cabinets" class=test/>
         Cabinets</tr>
         <input type="checkbox" rel="textbox1" name="Doors" />
         Doors
         <input type="checkbox" rel="textbox1" name="Drawers">
         Drawers
         <input type="checkbox" rel="textbox1" name="Drawer Fronts">
         Drawer Fronts
         <input type="checkbox" rel="textbox1" name="Handles">
         Handles
     </div>
    
     <textarea id="textbox1" ></textarea>
```

js

```
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
        var tb = "#"+$(this).attr('rel');
        let text_to_add = this.name + "\n";
        //when click a checkbox and show checked items in the text area
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $(tb).append(text_to_add);
        }else{
            let remove = this.name +"\n";
            //when a box is unchecked it clears the previously populated text from checkbox
            $(tb).text(function(i, text){
                return text .replace(text_to_add,'');
            });
        }
            
    })
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question. What is your intended outcome?

Comment: Sorry, my question was not very clear. my intended outcome is when the user types the projects name, it populates in the same text field as the checked boxes text but at the top of the field @JoelHager

Comment: just to be clear do you want to project name to appear above the textarea ? or inside the textarea but at first?

Comment: inside the textarea but at first @Elnatanvazana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i would come up with will be:
to store the exist value from the textarea everytime you change the text area value.

```
let existValue = ''
//inside the checkbox click function:
existValue = $(tb).val()
```

then to add an event listener to the input and everytime the input change to add the e.target.value to the exist value we created before

```
$('#pname').on('input', (e)=>{
  
  $('#textbox1').val(`${e.target.value}\n${existValue}`)
})
```

here is a working example: [working example](https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/dydZdmK?editors=1111)

Comment: I did some little changes, now it should work good. if it helped you please mark the answer.